# How to customizer jquery step

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

Am creating a step wizard using jquery-step library but I have failed to customize it. How can I customize it to replace the previous and next buttons when the user slides to the 3 step of "confirm in details" with yes or no buttons. This is the link to the jsfiddle with the work:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sunesis/xsd9ozrf/8/

```js
$(function () {
    $('#wizard').steps({
        headerTag:"h2",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {



            if ( newIndex === 1 ) {
                console.log('Verification Code')
            }
            if ( newIndex === 2 ) {
                console.log('Confirm details')
            }

            if(newIndex === 3){

            }
            return true;
        },
        labels:{
            finish: "&#10003;",
            next: "&#8702;",
            previous: "&#8701;"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do it would be use JQuery, you can access the button by `$('a[href$="#previous"]')`. To be able to use JQuery please add this link into your project `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

So try the code bellow, should work fine.
In fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1sxtLv0/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#wizard').steps({
        headerTag:"h2",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

            if ( newIndex === 1 ) {
                console.log('Verification Code')
            }
            if ( newIndex === 2 ) {
                console.log('Confirm details')
                $('a[href$="#previous"]').html('No');
                $('a[href$="#next"]').html('Yes');
            }

            if(newIndex === 3){
              $('a[href$="#previous"]').html('&#8701;');
              $('a[href$="#next"]').html('&#8702;');
            }
            return true;
        },
        labels:{
            finish: "&#10003;",
            next: "&#8702;",
            previous: "&#8701;"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :D. If you can just accept the answer I would appreciate bro.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not use in html file
please use jquery script same as below

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
```

i change your jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/Sunesis/xsd9ozrf/6/